# Simple Excel Data Validation didn't accept typed numbers

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I'm working with Excel 2013

I would like to make a custom Data Validation on cell A7 which allows:

- any numbers with length of 3

or

- any numbers with length of 6

I know the formula below is not optimized but this is only for testing combination AND OR purpose. While the formula below is accepted by the Data Validation window, when testing, none of the numbers are accepted.

```
=OR(AND(ISNUMBER(A7);LEN(A7)=3);AND(ISNUMBER(A7);LEN(A7)=6))
```

The same formula (reformatted for easy reading):

```
=OR(
    AND(
       ISNUMBER(A7);
       LEN(A7)=3
    );
    AND(
       ISNUMBER(A7);
       LEN(A7)=6
    )
)
```

Any idea why this formula didn't accept typed numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: works fine in Excel 2010 and 2013,    123   or 123456 etc is ok as expected,what value are you testing with in A7?     ( Keep in mind it also allows 123.12 for example)

Comment: Works fine in Excel 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occur if **A7** has been formatted to **Text**:

[image]

Comment: Forgot about that. Thanks.